# Many safes & a keypad - Rebus Puzzle

Tags: rebus

What is the image below trying to say?

[image: 123456789]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I believe this is

> **SAFETY IN NUMBERS**

because

> It's a T of safes in numbers 1-9

Comment: If this isn't it, I don't want to know what it is.

Comment: @TCooper: Obviously, it's the OP's "safe word". ;^P

Answer (score 3):

I guess the answer is

> T-Mobile, a brand name. The image is a common screen lock pattern for mobile phones.